# Store GA Client ID in User DB

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics

How can I retrieve Google Analytics Client ID from HTTP headers and store in a custom field in the User database table?

Comment: From what HTTP headers?

Comment: @jacobpeattie I think it's the Cookies HTTP Header